# Как рассчитать количество столбцов содержащих нули в многомерном массиве Java

Tags: java, массивы

Как в Java, посчитать количество столбцов неравномерного массива, содержащих число ноль? Возможно моё непонимание возникло из-за ошибочного представления как это всё работает, я перечислю как я понимаю, поправьте, если что-то неправильно:

1. объявили переменные и массив.
2. создали цикл в цикле, для того чтобы каждому элементу присвоить индекс и к нему можно было обращаться.
3. создаём ещё раз вложенный цикл для счётчика "count", берётся по порядку каждый элемент и сравнивается с нулём, если "истина" в счётчик добавляется результат, а break выкидывает нас во внешний цикл на следующую строку.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что mas.length - это количество строк, mas[i].length  - это длина каждой строки?

Ниже представлен код, который считает количество СТРОК содержащих нули, как выполнить аналогичное действие для столбцов?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int i;
        int j;
        int count = 0;
        int [][] mas = {{3, 0, 0, 6}, {4, 0, 1, 1}};

            for (i = 0; i < mas.length; i++) {
                 System.out.println();
              for (j = 0; j < mas[i].length; j++){
                 System.out.print(mas[i][j] + ", ");} }
                 System.out.println();

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------

           for (i = 0; i<mas.length; i++) {
              for (j = 0; j<mas[i].length; j++){
                if (mas[i][j] == 0){
                count++;
                break; } } }
        System.out.println("число строк содержащих нули = " + count); }}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.

Comment: проблема в том, что многомерный массив это совокупность одномерных,  идёт перебор элементов каждой строки, потом переходим на следующую строку и т.д. вот у меня и не укладывается как можно при расчёте двигаться не горизонтально, а по столбцам, чтобы при получении нужного результата переходить на следующий столбец? А что я хочу получить я написал конкретно, мне нужно число столбцов содержащих нули.

Comment: В комментарии вы пишете "мне нужно число столбцов, содержащих нули", а в коде пишете "число строк, содержащих нули". Что вам всё-таки надо получить?  
В вашей инициализации массива `{{3, 0, 0, 6}, {4, 0, 1, 1}};` что является в вашем понимании "строками", а что - "столбцами"? С программной точки зрения нет никакой разницы, что чем назвать. А если массив четырехмерный, что вы будете считать строками, а что - столбцами?

Comment: Павел, в коде выше я показываю всем, что посчитать кол-во строк с нулями я смог, и отсюда вытекает мой вопрос как тоже самое сделать со столбцами этой же матрицы, я не в силах его решить, поэтому и обратился к сообществу. Раз многомерный массив это совокупность одномерных, то фактически столбцов как таковых нет, так как все массивы это просто строка! Если перефразировать, то я бы хотел узнать как делать вертикальный перебор элементов многомерного массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задал этот же вопрос на англоязычной версии сайта, и получил моментальный ответ.

```
class Main { 

public static void main (String[] args) {
    int i;
    int j;
    int count = 0;
    int [][] arr = {{3, 0, 0, 6}, {4, 0, 1, 0}};

    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        System.out.println();
        for (j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + ", ");} }
            System.out.println();
        //--------------------------------------------------------------------

        for (i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)
            for (j = 0; j<arr[i].length; j++)
                if (arr[i][j] == 0) {
                    count++;
                    break; }
        System.out.println("the amount of rows containing zeros = " + count);

        //--------------------------------------------------------------------
        count=0;

        for (i = 0; i<arr[0].length; i++)
            for (j = 0; j<arr.length; j++)
                if (arr[j][i] == 0) {
                    count++;
                    break; }
        System.out.println("the amount of cols containing zeros = " + count);
}
}
```

Ссылка на решение моего вопроса:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/36639526/5942423

Comment: Ага, вот теперь хорошо стало. )

Answer (score 1):

```
   public int getZerosFrom(final int[][] numbers) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < numbers[i].length; j++) {
        if (numbers[i][j] == 0) {
          count++;
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

Comment: Спасибо, но считает неверно.

Comment: Скорей всего, у вас "столбцы" со "строками" перепутались, и этот код возвращает вам количество **строк**, содержащих нули. Попробуйте поменять местами `i` и `j`.